# How come my world suddenly changed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

One day I went to my world and all items had changed slightly. What is going on? Please help.

Comment: Hi Adela, can you provide more information? Examples of what changed (objects, landscape)? Was your spawn point changed? What is your current version? Did you update since the last time in your world? You can edit this information into your question.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is asked very unclearly, but maybe you mean that the texture of all items changed. You probably updated to a newer version, the textures got changed. This is normal and nothing to worry about, that's just how they look now. If you still want to continue to use the old ones, you can select "developer art" in the resource pack menu.